# Add Postgres database in Dockerfile

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile

I have a problem to solve well I have a Dockerfile with a tomcat image, I would still like to add a database there with postgres only I have a problem how to put it all together because I have no idea how to create a database in the dockerfile. Here is my Docker:

```
FROM tomcat:9.0.65-jdk11



RUN apt update
RUN apt install vim -y
RUN apt-get install postgres12
COPY ROOT.war 
WORKDIR /usr/local/tomcat
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

There is more but it is the usual mkdir and COPY of files. Do you have any idea ? maybe write a bash script that runs inside when building a container and creates my database ? I know, some people will write me that I should make ubuntu image install tomcat and postgres there, but I want to simplify my work in assigning permissions and shorten my work.

Answer (score 0):

Use docker-compose and create a database separately:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example
      POSTGRES_USER: user
    #volumes: # if you want to create your db 
    #  - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    # ports: # if you want to access it from your host
    #  - 5432:5432  
    
  tomcatapp:
    build: .
    image: tomcatapp
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Notes: the `Dockerfile` and `init.sql` (if you want to init your db) and `docker-compose.yml` should be in the same folder.